# gitlab-ci cannot upload golang built binary to nexus

Tags: go, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am trying to configure .gitlab-ci.yml for go application, however struggling to upload resulting binary to **Nexus**. I am using **curl** now, but it is failing

```
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 400 Content type could not be determined
```

Comment: Include the job specification in the question.

Comment: Can you add the curl command, the message says Content Type is missing

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong. the problem was on NEXUS' side. In settings of nexus repository "allow rewrite" was unticked and again ticked, so it worked.